# Get element by nested ng-reflect-model value

Tags: cypress

I've come to a snag with selecting this particular element. I have a series of tr elements, and I need to select one of those based on the content within. A simplified tree is below with the likely selectors to use:

```
<tr data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW">...</tr>
<tr data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW">...</tr>
<tr data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW">
    <td>
        <input data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_NAME" ng-reflect-model="Doc">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW">
    <td>
        <input data-test="FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_NAME" ng-reflect-model="Admin">
    </td>
</tr>
```

So in this case I'd be looking to select the tr that contains "Admin" or "Doc" depending on the object pass into my function. Code snippet below:

```
 export function selectOptionsFees(options: E2EOptionsFees[]) {
  cy.getDataTestTag(DataTestTags.OPTIONS_FEES_SUMMARY).first().click();
  options.forEach((option: E2EOptionsFees) => {
    cy.getDataTestTag(DataTestTags.FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW)
      .contains('tr', option.name)
      .within(() => {
```

The 'contains' line is where I'm stuck, and option.name would correspond to either "Doc" or "Admin" in the html above. All of the other cases up until now had text in the input so the code above worked, but this one has me stumped.

Edit: I got it figured out! In case anyone else comes across this, look up the jQuery documentation often. Turns out it is much better than the Cypress documentation (no fault on the Cypress folks, they do show that it piggybacks on jQuery). This is all it takes:

`` cy.get(`[data-test=FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_NAME][ng-reflect-model="${option.name}"]`) ``

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be to check for the attribute with 'have.attr':

```
cy.getDataTestTag(DataTestTags.FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW)
    .should('have.attr', 'ng-reflect-model', option.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try and match the ng-reflect-model attribute:

```
cy.getDataTestTag(DataTestTags.FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_ROW)
    .find(`tr input[ng-reflect-model="${option.name}"]`)
```

Comment: That's definitely progress, I was trying to get the variable attached to the attribute like you did but I wasn't quite there. It's still not finding it though, and I have no clue why. 

If I throw the timeout error into the console it shows that the .find is properly applying to the eight tr elements that have the data tag, and I can find the ng-reflect-model values from within the console results, but something is still stopping Cypress from finding it.

Comment: Well I got it figured out. After spending more time than I care to admit, it turns out it was really easy when I went away from the Cypress documentation and looked at the jQuery docs instead.

```cy.get(`[data-test=FEE_SELECTOR_FEE_NAME][ng-reflect-model="${option.name}"]`).parent().parent()```